# Combine the output of two queries into a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to combine the below queries into a single output, I am not sure on how to use union as I have bunch of conditions on the queries as well. In the final output I also need to Subtract the result of negative_sales column from query 2 from Net value column from query 1

```
SELECT storenumber,
       bbbtendertypetext,
       SUM(financialamounttendered) - SUM(financialchangeamount) AS NET_VALUE,
       COUNT(transactionid) AS Transaction_Count
FROM   [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender]
WHERE  transactiondatetime > '2022-09-21 00:00:00.000'
       AND transactiondatetime < '2022-09-22 00:03:00.000'
GROUP  BY storenumber, bbbtendertypetext
ORDER  BY storenumber 

SELECT storenumber,
       bbbtendertypetext,
       SUM(financialamounttendered) AS negative_Net_Sales,
       COUNT(transactionid) AS Transaction_Count
FROM   [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender_correct]
       where transactiondatetime > '2022-09-21 00:00:00.000'
       AND transactiondatetime < '2022-09-22 00:03:00.000'
GROUP  BY storenumber, bbbtendertypetext
ORDER  BY storenumber
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot write just one query using an INNER or LEFT join on storenumber and bbbtendertypetext?

Comment: You're going to have to show sample data and your desired output as mentioned above for us to suggest an optimal solution. Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 0):

For example so

```
select s1.storenumber storenumber
     , s2.storenumber storenumber2
     , s1.bbbtendertypetext bbbtendertypetext
     , s2.bbbtendertypetext bbbtendertypetext2
     , s1.NET_VALUE  NET_VALUE
     , s1.Transaction_Count Transaction_Count
     , s2.Transaction_Count Transaction_Count2
     , s2.negative_Net_Sales negative_Net_Sales
     , s1.NET_VALUE - s2.negative_Net_Sales differnt
from (
    SELECT storenumber,
           bbbtendertypetext,
           SUM(financialamounttendered) - SUM(financialchangeamount) AS NET_VALUE,
           COUNT(transactionid) AS Transaction_Count
    FROM   [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender]
    WHERE  transactiondatetime > '2022-09-21 00:00:00.000'
           AND transactiondatetime < '2022-09-22 00:03:00.000'
    GROUP  BY storenumber, bbbtendertypetext
    ORDER  BY storenumber 
) s1 left join (
    SELECT storenumber,
           bbbtendertypetext,
           SUM(financialamounttendered) AS negative_Net_Sales,
           COUNT(transactionid) AS Transaction_Count
    FROM   [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender_correct]
           AND transactiondatetime > '2022-09-21 00:00:00.000'
           AND transactiondatetime < '2022-09-22 00:03:00.000'
    GROUP  BY storenumber, bbbtendertypetext
    ORDER  BY storenumber
) s2 on s1.storenumber = s2.storenumber
```

Note that there is no where section in the second query

Comment: Thank you I will try this out.  and yes i removed one part query and forgot to include where clause after tender_correct

Comment: The query works in a way

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to combine the `SUM` values of query `A`, and query `B` above (unique values `GROUPED BY` `storenumber` and `bbbtendertypetext`), you can use two `CTE`'s then `INNER JOIN` them on `storenumber` to get your result set and do an overall `SUM` from there.

If you want a more non-aggregated result set, remove the `GROUP BY` and `SUM`'s from the main query below the `CTE`'s.

```
WITH a AS (SELECT storenumber,
       bbbtendertypetext,
       transactiondatetime,
       SUM(financialchangeamount) AS charge_amount,
       COUNT(transactionid) AS Transaction_Count
FROM   [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender]
  GROUP  BY storenumber, bbbtendertypetext, transactiondatetime),
     b AS (SELECT storenumber,
       bbbtendertypetext,
       transactiondatetime,
       SUM(financialamounttendered) AS negative_Net_Sales,
       COUNT(transactionid) AS Transaction_Count
FROM   [AceTLogData].[Tlog].[tender_correct]
   GROUP  BY storenumber, bbbtendertypetext, transactiondatetime)
SELECT a.storenumber,
       a.bbbtendertypetext,
       SUM(a.charge_amount) AS charge_amount,
       SUM(b.negative_Net_Sales) AS negative_Net_Sales ,
       SUM(a.charge_amount - b.negative_Net_Sales) AS NET_VALUE,
       SUM(a.Transaction_Count) AS Transaction_Count
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.storenumber = b.storenumber
WHERE  a.transactiondatetime 
  BETWEEN '2022-09-21 00:00:00.000' AND  '2022-09-22 00:03:00.000'
GROUP BY a.storenumber, a.bbbtendertypetext
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J1a9lrjG).

Comment: **Note**: if I did not understand your question correctly, please let me know and update your question above accordingly; it's important to provide sample data and your expected output using your sample data to avoid confusion.

Comment: No problem. Is this what you were trying to achieve? I took a shot in the dark with this one. If so, or if someone else's answer fits what you wanted, you should accept an answer to inform others that your issue is resolved, see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).